# when I switch camera，camera control is bing valid

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to swith camera type in my threejs Demo，so I read an official demo ：https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera

But some errors occur when I test my demo. When I press P to use cameraPerspective，it works well;But when I use O to switch cameraOrtho,cameracontrol doesn't work——I cannot rotate or move my model sample.

There is my code：

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>3D-earth</title>
    <script src="JSandCSS/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JSandCSS/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JSandCSS/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="JSandCSS/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSandCSS/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSandCSS/qrcode.js"></script>
    <script src="JSandCSS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSandCSS/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
    <script src="JSandCSS/Projector.js"></script>
    <link href="JSandCSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 50%;">
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var group = new THREE.Group;
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            var objects = [];
            init();

            var container, stats, titleinfo;
            scene.add(group);



            var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                /*   Roushness:1,
                   Metalness:0,*/
                map: textureLoader.load("model/earth/texture.jpg"),
                /* normalMap:textureLoader.load("model/earth/normal.jpg"),*/
                specularMap: textureLoader.load("model/earth/specular.jpg"),
                lightMap: textureLoader.load("model/earth/light.jpg"),
                side:THREE.DoubleSide,
            });




            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.load('model/earth/earth.obj', function(obj) {
                obj.traverse(function(child) {
                    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        child.material = mat;
                    }
                });
                mesh = obj;
                obj.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
                group.add(obj);
            });


            var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
            light.position.set(300, 400, 200);
            light.intensity.set = 0.1;
            scene.add(light);
            scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333));






            var cameraPerspective = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            cameraPerspective.position.set(200, 200, 200);
            cameraPerspective.lookAt(scene.position);

            cameraOrtho = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -4, window.innerWidth / 4, window.innerHeight / 4, window.innerHeight / -4, -10000, 10000);

            ActiveCamera = cameraPerspective;


            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            renderer.render(scene, ActiveCamera);
            renderer.setClearColor(0x808080, 0.5); 


            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(ActiveCamera);
            controls.minDistance = 200;
            controls.maxDistance = 400;
            controls.autoRotate = true;
            controls.addEventListener('change', render); 
            animate(); 
            window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false); 
            document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);



            function render() {
                /*group.rotation.y -= 0.004;*/
                renderer.render(scene, ActiveCamera);
            } 

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();
            } 

            function onKeyDown(event) {
                switch(event.keyCode) {
                    case 79:
                        ActiveCamera = cameraOrtho;                                                     
                    case 80:
                        ActiveCamera = cameraPerspective;
                }
            }

            function handleWindowResize() {
                HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
                WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
                renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                ActiveCamera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
                ActiveCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            } 

        </script>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: can you share your code on jsfiddle

Comment: I am not falimiar with  jsfiddle.....I edit my question and put all my code.It is  a little surprise that when I only use one camera in my code it works well,but when I use two and try to switch between them,the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with single camera object of CombinedCamera and

to switch between Perspective and Ortho use below code.

```
//initial 
var camera = new THREE.CombinedCamera($(canvasHold).innerWidth(), $(canvasHold).innerHeight(), 75, .1, 3e3, -5e3, 5e3);
camera.toOrthographic();

function switchCamera()
{
  if(ortho) // Add condition
  {
     camera.toOrthographic();
     camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
     camera.zoom = .5;
     camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
     camera.lookAt(scene.position);
     camera.setFov(75);
  }
  else
  {
     camera.toPerspective();
     camera.zoom = 1;
     camera.setFov(45);
  }
}
```

> Note: Please change variables and values according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also need to measure the distance of two point of the 3D model，But Raycaster.js don’t support CombinedCamera.I don‘t know how to measure distance with CombinedCamera and Raycaster.js，is there any solution？

Comment: My IDE echo:"THREE.Raycaster: Unsupported camera type."

Comment: You can mark this as a correct ;). And for distance calculation, you should try with simple maths formula. Let me know if you require more help.